# Breeze Entity not getting saved after modified with in fetchEntity method

Tags: breeze, savechanges

```
 $.each(vm.ListBox2(), function (index2, value2) {

            if (vm.ListBox2()[index2].IsNewDxCode == false)
            {
                return datacontext.fetchEntity("EpisodeDxM00Rel", vm.ListBox2()[index2].Id).then(function (result) {
                    var episodeDxM00RelEntity = result.entity;
                    episodeDxM00RelEntity.SortOrder = index2;
                    vm.save();
                });

            }

        });


 dc.fetchEntity = function (entityName, key) {
        return manager.fetchEntityByKey(entityName, key);
 };

 dc.saveChanges = function () {
        return manager.saveChanges()
                .fail(dc.saveFailed);
    };
```

I am trying to modify the SortOrder property of an entity inside fetchEntity method and calling the save method after it. When I check database, the changes are not persisted there. I do not see any errors in console.

Comment: Are you using Knockout or Angular or some other library for data-binding?

Comment: Could you share the code for the fetchEntity and vm.save() functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using Breeze with Knockout all of the properties of your entity are observables.  Therefore, you need to set them instead of overwriting their value.

```
episodeDxM00RelEntity.SortOrder(index2);
```

KO.observables of course have two main methods - get() and set(value).